# Changing the <td> element of a table using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have been learning about DOMs lately and have been stuck on a problem for days. For some reason, I cannot change the contents of a html table. I have been looking at w3 schools HTML and using DOM to change the table element.

Here is the code for the table :

```
<div id="courseSummaryContainer" class="tab">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="summaryTable courseSummary smallFontTable" summary="Health Care by province">
        <thead><tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date of entry</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Submission entry type</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="row-even">
            <td>Illinois</td>
            <td>Online system</td>
            <td>201602</td>
            <td>0100</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Final</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-odd">
            <td>Alabama</td>
            <td>Regional area health</td>
            <td>201606</td>
            <td>0100</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Final</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-even">
            <td>Illinois</td>
            <td>Online system</td>
            <td>201602</td>
            <td>0100</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Final</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I have been trying to do is change the names of the states and their values. To do so, I have been trying to access the `<td>` element.

To change the contents, I tried the following: 
Say for example want to change "Illinois" to "Georgia" I tried the following

```
document.getElementById("table.summaryTable.courseSummary.sm‌allFontTable").rows[‌2].cells;
 x[1].innerHTML = "Georgia";
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong however the console keeps giving errors all the time stating the values are null.

Can somebody please offer their guidance?

Comment: As the name suggests, `getElementById` gives you the element that possesses an ID attribute with the given value. You have no elements with `id="table.summaryTable.courseSummary.smallFontTable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document#querySelector`. In this case a simple selector can be `.row-even > td:first-child` because you only have one `.row-even`.

**How can you be more specific?**

If you've got multiple `.row-even`, by using `tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:first-child`.

If you have multiple tables with `.row-even`, you can add the id of the container `#courseSummaryContainer .row-even > td:first-child` or the class of the table `.courseSummary .row-even > td:first-child`.

```js
var td = document.querySelector('.row-even > td:first-child');

td.innerText = 'Georgia';
```

```html
<div id="courseSummaryContainer" class="tab">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="summaryTable courseSummary smallFontTable" summary="Health Care by province">
        <thead><tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date of entry</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Submission entry type</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="row-even">
            <td>Illinois</td>
            <td>Online system</td>
            <td>201602</td>
            <td>0100</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Final</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-odd">
            <td>Alabama</td>
            <td>Regional area health</td>
            <td>201606</td>
            <td>0100</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Final</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick question say if I want to change the "Date of entry " for "illinois" to "null" would I say : var td = document.querySelector('.row-even > td:third-child');

td.innerText = 'null';

Comment: Also if there are more than 1 '.row-even' will this code still work?

Comment: See my expanded description with more cases.

Comment: `:nth-child` is 1-based.

Comment: @squint - indeed. I feel ashamed :)

Comment: '.row-even > td:nth-child(3)'

Comment: @marshmellooooooos: FYI, depending on your required browser support, you don't need odd/even classes. You can use the CSS `:odd` and `:even` pseudo classes instead.

Comment: I have multiple row-even and row-odd in other tables on my friend's website. I tried running the following that Ori Dori suggested :                                  var td = document.querySelector('#courseSummaryContainer .row-even > td:first-child);

td.innerText = 'Georgia';                                                                                 This for someone reason did not work I am not sure why though.

Comment: @marshmellooooooos - recheck the selectors by removing parts of them, and seeing when it fails, try `#courseSummaryContainer`, then `#courseSummaryContainer .row-even`, then `#courseSummaryContainer .row-even > td`, etc... `console.log` the results.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the right element in the DOM, if you are going to use the function: "getElementById", you need to pass it the id of the element that you want to have, like:

html:

```
<div id="courseSummaryContainer" class="tab">
        <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" class="summaryTable courseSummary smallFontTable" summary="Health Care by province">
            //... Table content
        </table>
</div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[‌2].cells;
```